# Making a bind-mount take effect only in the context of the current process and its descendants

Tags: chroot, fork, bind-mount, unshare

I have 2 files: /MyDir/a and /MyDir/MySubDir/b and am running a bash script, to which I want to add code to make file /a point to file /b, but only in the current process and its descendants.

In hopes of making /MyDir/a point to /MyDir/MySubDir/b in the context of only the current process (not including its descendants, yet) I tried to first make the current process run in its own mount namespace by running a small C program in my script that performs

```
unshare(CLONE_NEWNS)
```

and then

```
mount --bind /MyDir/MySubDir/b /MyDir/a.
```

Unfortunately, this didn't work as I expected since the mount was still visible by other processes, despite the system call reporting success.

In another attempt, I tried to make the mount from the C code by calling

```
mount("/MyDir/a", "/MyDir/MySubDir/b", "ext3", MS_BIND, null)
```

But this didn't work as the mount didn't take effect at all (despite the call reporting success).

Is there a way of making /MyDir/a point to /MyDir/MySubDir/b in the context of only the current process and its descendants using a bash script?

I also read a little about chroot, but this applies only to the / directory...
Is there anything similar to chroot that applies only to a particular subdirectory?

Thanks for your time!

Comment: commands executed as the root user, right?

Comment: Yes, that's right

Comment: "But this didn't work as the mount didn't take effect at all" How did you check this? How are your C program and the shell command `mount` related? Did you `execve()` from the C program to the shell?

Comment: This writing and reading was done within the C program?

Comment: No, the writing was done by vi, before any mount operations, and reading was done by cat from within the bash script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A shell-only solution would be:

For interactive shell:

```
# unshare --mount
# mount --bind /MyDir/MySubDir/b /MyDir/a
#
```

non-interactively, before a script that doesn't have to know about these settings:

```
# unshare --mount sh -c 'mount --bind /MyDir/MySubDir/b /MyDir/a; exec somethingelse'
```

The [unshare](https://manpages.debian.org/stretch/util-linux/unshare.1.en.html) manpage also warns about shared subtree mounts . If you have to disable them, consider adding for example `--make-private` to mount.

As Hauke told, you have to be sure to not leave the namespace just after having created it, because it will disappear.

If needed there's a method to maintain a namespace without process. Since it involves mount, it's just a bit more tricky for a mount namespace. Here's an interactive example for this:

```
shell1# unshare --mount
shell1# echo $$
12345
shell1#

shell2# : > /root/mntreference
shell2# mount --bind /proc/12345/ns/mnt /root/mntreference
```

Now as long as this reference is kept mounted, the namespace won't disappear even if there's no process using it anymore. Using `nsenter --mount=/root/mntreference` will enter it, so you can easily run additional scripts in it.

Using the equivalent in C shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: No need to use `exec` with `unshare`: `unshare --mount bash` is enough. Then the `mount --bind` can simply be done in the shell.

Comment: Indeed, that was for a "one liner". I removed exec where useless (kept one exec, no need to have an useless sh staying around)

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately you still haven't explained how the C program and the script are related.

A possible (and here probable) reason for the problem is: You call the C program from the script but the namespace change is effective only within the C program (and possible children). After that program exists the situation is unchanged for all following commands.

You should start a shell from the C program by calling `execve()` for the intended shell.

Comment: The C program is indeed called from within the script. Now I understand why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

As others have explained, you need to create the namespace (with `unshare`) and run your command into it.

If you need a pre-made solution that does NOT require root, does signal and return status handling correctly, you can use the `faketree` utility. It is available [on github here](https://github.com/enfabrica/enkit/tree/master/faketree), there's a [blog post](https://blog.enfabrica.net/different-file-system-views-for-different-tools-a425f13bb7f0) that describes its use and purpose.

Could be used as:

```
faketree --mount /MyDir/MySubDir/b:/MyDir/a -- /path/to/your/script.sh
```